# Desbordamiento del búfer de scanf() usado en la sentencia switch || c++

Tags: c++, scanf

```
int main (){

    switch (opcion) {
    case 1: //Declaraciones
    break;

    case 2: //Declaraciones
    break;

    case 3:
    cout << " Escribe una cadena de caracteres\n ";
    char mensaje[100];
    scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z   ]s", &mensaje, 100);

    cout << " ";
    cout << mensaje; 

    cout << " \n ";
    break;
}
```

El problema esta con scanf, deseo que la persona pueda escribir una secuencia String (la razón de esos condicionales "%[0-9a-zA-Z ]s" , es que la persona pueda escribir espacios y sean contados y luego representados) cuál se guarde y repita con el cout<< mensaje; más tarde, pero este se desborda scanf y al final me imprime mil caracteres sin pedirme que escriba algo, si no está dentro de la sentencia switch, éste se ejecuta como tal normalmente, pero dentro se desborda.

Comment: Esto: `scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z   ]s", &mensaje, 100);` es **incorrecto**, y no tiene nada que ver con que esté dentro o no de un `switch( )`. Ese `&` no debería estar ahí. ¿ Error al copiar el código, o realmente lo tienes así ?

Comment: @Trauma ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?, aún removiéndolo no llego a mi objetivo.

Comment: No estoy seguro de lo que quieres hacer: `scanf( "%[0-9a-zA-Z ]s" )` a mi me funciona bien. El único caso *raro* es que el primer caracter leido sea incorrecto, en cuyo caso si el *buffer* no está inicializado, **si** puedes tener problemas. ¿ El `cout <<` lo estás haciendo **dentro** o **fuera** del `switch( )` ?

Comment: Sí, el scanf( "%[0-9a-zA-Z ]s" ) funciona bien pero al ingresarlo en un switch se imprimen los 100 caracteres inentendibles que reserve en la variable char, sin permitirme escribir algo. esto es lo que se escribe.╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: Lo siento, pero ya te digo que a mi me funciona bien. Tendrás que poner un [mcve] para poder reproducir tu problema; no puedo serte de ayuda sin algo que pueda reproducir.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s` está fallando y no toca el array mensaje.

Te está tomando el Enter de como sea que leas el valor de `opcion` del usuario y falla la lista de caracteres `[0-9a-zA-Z   ]`. Si lo cambiaras por `[0-9a-zA-Z\n   ]` yo creo que verías que sí te lee lo que escribes (sólo presiona Ctrl+Z y luego Enter para que avance al siguiente paso).

Supongo que lo estás corriendo en modo debug y por eso ves esos valores. En release puede haber lo que sea en esa memoria no inicializada.

Te recomiendo instanciar el array así: `char message[100] = {};` Así todos los elementos se inicializarán en 0 y `cout` no tratará de imprimir lo que sea que haya en memoria en el momento.

Y como recomendación, en lugar de

```
scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z   ]s", &mensaje, 100);
```

tal vez deberías poner

```
scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z   ]s", mensaje, 100);
```

o

```
scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z   ]s", &mensaje[0], 100);
```